# Ошибка с декодированием кода и сформами pygame и PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, utf-8, pygame

Столкнулся с проблемой, питон не хочет декодировать правильно код.

Вот сам код

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pygame 
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
import random
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(u"Игра")
        Form.resize(589, 479)
        Form.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
"background-color: white;\n"
"text-align: center;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton{\n"
"background-color:white;\n"
"width:150px;\n"
"height:125px;\n"
"font-size:150px;\n"
"border: none;\n"
"text-align: center;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"background-color: light silver\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 339, 571, 137))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 20, 551, 51))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "2"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "3"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "   )                                                                      ПОЛЕ ДЛЯ ОТВЕТОВ"))
class Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Form, self).__init__()
#Create form and init UI
#Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.dialog = Dialog()
        ui = Ui_Form()
        ui.setupUi(self)
        ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.okno)
        # ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.show_dialog)
        ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.hide_dialog)
    def okno(self):
        #Вывод окна
#        sys.exit(app.exec_())
        
        pyGame()
    def show_dialog(self):
        self.dialog.show()
  
    def hide_dialog(self):
        self.dialog.hide()
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
#Form.show()
   
    
        
        # app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        # w = Form()
        # w.show()
        # sys.exit(app.exec_())
                             
def pyGame():
    with open ('zagadki.txt', 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        linesNumbers = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
        zagadkaNumber = random.choice(linesNumbers)
        zagadka = lines[zagadkaNumber]
    # Настройка pygame
    pygame.init()

    # Настройка окна
    windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((1250, 1250), 0, 32)
    pygame.display.set_caption(u'Привет, мир!')

    # Назначение цветов
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    RED = (255, 0, 0)
    GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
    BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

    # Назначение шрифтов
    basicFont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

    # Настройка текста
    text = basicFont.render(zagadka, True, WHITE, BLUE)
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.centerx = windowSurface.get_rect().centerx
    textRect.centery = windowSurface.get_rect().centery
 
    # Нанесение на поверхность белого фона
    windowSurface.fill(WHITE)

    # Нанесение на поверхность зеленого многоугольника
    pygame.draw.polygon(windowSurface, GREEN, ((146, 0), (291, 106), (236, 277), (56, 277), (0, 106)))

    # Нанесение на поверхность синих линий
    pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, BLUE, (60, 60), (120, 60), 4)
    pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, BLUE, (120, 60), (60, 120))
    pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, BLUE, (60, 120), (120, 120), 4)

    # Нанесение на поверхность синего круга
    pygame.draw.circle(windowSurface, BLUE, (300, 50), 20, 0)

    #Нанесение на поверхность красного эллипса.
    pygame.draw.ellipse(windowSurface, RED, (300, 250, 40, 80), 1)

    #Нанесение на поверхность фонового прямоугольника для текста.
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, RED, (textRect.left - 500, textRect.top - 500, textRect.width + 100, textRect.height + 100))

    # Получение массива пикселов поверхности
    pixArray = pygame.PixelArray(windowSurface)
    pixArray[480][380] = BLACK
    del pixArray

    # Нанесение текста на поверхность
    windowSurface.blit(text, textRect)

    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        w = Form()
        w.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
    # Запуск игрового цикла
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN :
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    kones()
                    sys.exit()
                    kones()
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                
                sys.exit()
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Form()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

вот текстовый файл

```
На обед сыночку Ване Мама варит суп в… 1-стакане 2-кастрюле 3-чайнике
2
Попросила мама Юлю Ей чайку налить в…  1-чашку 2-кастрюлю 3-бочку
1
Во дворе трещит мороз — Шапку ты одень на… 1-нос 2-ногу 3-голову
3
Подобрать себе я смог пару варежек для... 1-ног 2-носа 3-рук
3
И капризна, и упряма, В детский сад не хочет… 1-мама 2-папа 3-дочка
3
Скачет наш котенок ловко, Очень любит он… 1-молоко 2-морковку 3-чай
1
Ночью каждое оконце Слабо освещает ... 1-солнце 2-фонарик 3-луна
3
Простой вопрос для малышей: Кого боится кот?.. 1-слонов 2-собак 3-мышей 
2
```

и вот сама ошибка

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 200: character maps to <undefined>
```

Так же сразу хотел бы задать второй вопрос, почему при выводе форм *pygame* и *PyQt5* одновременно они виснут и не отвечают. Почему это происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я добавил `encoding='UTF-8'` в строку `with open('zagadki.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:` и внес некоторые правки, которые отметил для вас. Что делает функция `pyGame` и не смотрел.

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pygame 
from pygame.locals import *


def pyGame():
    with open('zagadki.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:               # +++ encoding='UTF-8'
        lines = file.readlines()
        linesNumbers = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
        zagadkaNumber = random.choice(linesNumbers)
        zagadka = lines[zagadkaNumber]
    # Настройка pygame
    pygame.init()

    # Настройка окна
    windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((1250, 1250), 0, 32)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Привет, мир!')

    # Назначение цветов
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    RED = (255, 0, 0)
    GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
    BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

    # Назначение шрифтов
    basicFont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

    # Настройка текста
    text = basicFont.render(zagadka, True, WHITE, BLUE)
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.centerx = windowSurface.get_rect().centerx
    textRect.centery = windowSurface.get_rect().centery

    # Нанесение на поверхность белого фона
    windowSurface.fill(WHITE)

    # Нанесение на поверхность зеленого многоугольника
    pygame.draw.polygon(windowSurface, GREEN, ((146, 0), (291, 106), (236, 277), (56, 277), (0, 106)))

    # Нанесение на поверхность синих линий
    pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, BLUE, (60, 60), (120, 60), 4)
    pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, BLUE, (120, 60), (60, 120))
    pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, BLUE, (60, 120), (120, 120), 4)

    # Нанесение на поверхность синего круга
    pygame.draw.circle(windowSurface, BLUE, (300, 50), 20, 0)

    #Нанесение на поверхность красного эллипса.
    pygame.draw.ellipse(windowSurface, RED, (300, 250, 40, 80), 1)

    #Нанесение на поверхность фонового прямоугольника для текста.
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, RED, (textRect.left - 500, textRect.top - 500, textRect.width + 100, textRect.height + 100))

    # Получение массива пикселов поверхности
    pixArray = pygame.PixelArray(windowSurface)
    pixArray[480][380] = BLACK
    del pixArray

    # Нанесение текста на поверхность
    windowSurface.blit(text, textRect)

#??????????????????????????????????????????????????
#    if __name__ == "__main__":
#        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#        w = Form()
#        w.show()
#        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    # Запуск игрового цикла
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN :
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
#???                    kones()
#                    sys.exit()
#???                    kones()
                    return                                              # +++
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                return                                                  # +++
#                sys.exit()


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(u"Игра")
        Form.resize(589, 479)
        Form.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
"background-color: white;\n"
"text-align: center;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton{\n"
"background-color:white;\n"
"width:150px;\n"
"height:125px;\n"
"font-size:150px;\n"
"border: none;\n"
"text-align: center;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"background-color: light silver\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 339, 571, 137))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 20, 551, 51))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "2"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "3"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "ПОЛЕ ДЛЯ ОТВЕТОВ"))


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("class Dialog")
        self.resize(1200, 200)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: red;')
        #pass


class Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Form, self).__init__()
#        self.dialog = Dialog()                              # -
        ui = Ui_Form()
        ui.setupUi(self)

        self.dialog = Dialog()                               # +

        ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.okno)

        ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.show_dialog)    # +
        ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.hide_dialog)    # +

    def okno(self):
        #Вывод окна
        pyGame()

    def show_dialog(self):
        self.dialog.show()

    def hide_dialog(self):
        self.dialog.hide()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Form()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ!!!

Comment: хотя я рано порадовался-_-

Comment: Ошибка все равно вылезает(

Comment: @nekitt проверьте чтобы файл  `zagadki.txt` был в кодировке `UTF-8`

Comment: спасибо, все заработало